# Can't accurate coords to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a camera capture pen all I want to do is sending the exact of source image coordinates to canvas depending on mouseX, mouseY it's something like a crop tool.
here is pen code source: https://codepen.io/Mahmoud-Zakaria/pen/QKmZBO

```
<a href="#modal-wrap">
  <div class="camera-square"></div>
  <div class="camera-square"></div>
  <div class="camera-square"></div>
  <div class="camera-square"></div>
  <span class="camera-circle"></span>
</a>


<div class="camera" id="camera">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/306097/rfAMYT.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="modal-wrap" id="modal-wrap">
  <div class="modal-surround" id="modal-surround"></div>
  <div class="modal" id="modal">
    <canvas id="modal-target" class="modal-target"></canvas>
    <a href="#" class="modal-close" id="modal-close">&times;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
window.location.href = '#'

var cameraCursor = document.querySelector('[href="#modal-wrap"]')
var cameraWrap = document.getElementById('camera')
var modalTarget = document.getElementById('modal-target');
const modalTargetContext = modalTarget.getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
var sound = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]
var modalClose = document.getElementById('modal-close')


window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  cameraCursor.style.top = e.clientY - (cameraCursor.offsetHeight - (cameraCursor.offsetHeight / 2)) + 'px';
  cameraCursor.style.left = e.clientX - (cameraCursor.offsetWidth - (cameraCursor.offsetWidth / 2)) + 'px';
})


cameraCursor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  this.style.cursor = "default"
  this.style.opacity = "0"
  sound.play()
  var o = (cameraCursor.offsetWidth / 2)
  var z = (cameraCursor.offsetHeight / 2)
  var x = e.clientX - o;
  var y = e.clientY - z;
  modalTargetContext.drawImage(img, x, y, img.offsetWidth, img.offsetHeight, 0, 0, img.offsetWidth / 2, img.offsetHeight / 2);
})

modalClose.addEventListener('click', function(){
  cameraCursor.style.opacity = '1'
  cameraCursor.style.cursor = "none"
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. The `canvas` in the modal has no specific width & height set. This defaults it to 300x150, applying any width/height via css will only scale it. You should set it explicitly in the html, or better, read the desired width&height via `getBoundingClientRect()` and then apply it before drawing onto it.

Inside the click handler:

```
var bounds = modalTarget.getBoundingClientRect()
modalTarget.width = bounds.width
modalTarget.height = bounds.height
modalTargetContext.drawImage(...)
```

2. Your image has a vertical css offset of -100px, this needs to be factored into the coordinates.

e.g:

```
var y = e.clientY - z + 100;
```

[See the updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mobVex)